# Check if string contains a character from list - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am typescript learner and currently using the below logic to find if a string is having specific characters from an array. But it needs to be tuned I believe. Sorry if it looks a little dumb. Kindly help throwing some light on how to fix this.

```
myList.forEach((charac) => {
    if (myString.includes(charac)) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

**My input**:

```
myList = [1,2,3]
myString = John1
```

**Required output**:

```
Error
```

**UPDATE**:

Considering I have the option of removing the error character, I modified my code like this:

```
myList.forEach((charac) => {
        myString = myString.replace(errorCharacter, appConstants.EMPTY);
    }); 
console.log(myString);
```

But this replaces only the first instance of errorCharacter. i.e

For `John1`, I get a console output as `John`.
But for `John 111`, I get a console output as `John11`.

I know we have to include `/gi` to replace all. But don't know how to append the characters dynamically.

Adding like:

```
myString = myString.replace(errorCharacter + "/gi", appConstants.EMPTY);
```

didn't work as well.

Comment: what's the problem is your code? It is giving the required output. What else do you want to achieve?

Comment: No. I dont see the output. It is not returning the Error message.

Comment: How it is related to typescript, while you are not defining type of variables.

Comment: Please check my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct if you use strings for your digits.

```
const myList = ['1','2','3']
const myString = "John1"

myList.forEach((charac) => {
    if (myString.includes(charac)) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

---

A much cleaner way to write this would be:

```
const myList = ['1','2','3']
const myString = "John1"

const hasChar = myList.some((charac) => myString.includes(charac));
if(hasChar) {
    console.log('Error');
}
```

Comment: Please check my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method, which when given a character, will split a string up by that character, but, when given an empty string it will split it my character.

Also the `includes` method on arrays returns a boolean for whether that given value exists in the array. Also, your number might be causing an issue, so you can cast it by adding it to an empty string. So together

```js
let str = "John1"
arrayOfValues.forEach(cantContain => {
   if(str.split('').includes(cantContain + "")) {
      // your code
   }
});
```

Comment: Please check my update.

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on your updated question.

You can use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`.

As you've pointed out `replace()` method replaces only the first occurrence so since you want to replace all the occurrences `replaceAll()` should work for you.